# excel get row range or actual values based on matching value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following structure in my excel sheet.

```
          A         B
      ---------   -----  
 1 |  category1   test1
 2 |  category1   test2
 3 |  category1   test3
 4 |  category2   test4
 5 |  category2   test5
 6 |  category3   test6
 7 |  category3   test7
 8 |  category3   test8
 9 |  category3   test9
10 |  category4   test10
```

Can you suggest a way using **EXCEL functions** (**not VBA**) of getting back either the **range** or the **actual values** given the **category text** as input?

For example given `category2` I need to get back something like `B4:B5` or `"test4"/"test5"`

I need a way of doing this dynamically i.e. I need a function that will still work if I do an insert and add a new value to a category e.g.

```
          A         B
      ---------   -----  
 4 |  category2   test4
 5 |  category2   test5
 6 |  category2   test200
 7 |  category2   test203
```

Now given `category2` I would get back `B4:B7`

Comment: Are categories always contiguous?

Comment: @Taosique hmmm yes category names are grouped contiguously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming categories are always contiguous, you can get reference:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH("category2",$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A:$A,"category2"))
```

Comment: I get back #VALUE! Will it work like that or should this be used as input to another function?

Comment: Yes, you can use it with `=INDEX(OFFSET(......),<number_of_row>).` `<number_of_row>` is 1, 2, 3... i.e. number of row *found*. If no matching rows found, it will return `#N/A!`.

Answer (score 0):

If your category always starts with the same prefix, you could use something like:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("category"&$C$1,B:B,0),2,4,1)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("category"&($C$1+1),B:B,0)-1,2,4,1)
```

So if you put "2" in C1, it will return "B4:B5"

This also assumes that categories are named in increasing values, so if there was no category3 this would not work.